# Restore MQ Explorer without backup but install directory

Tags: ibm-mq

I did Windows upgrade for my machine but I didn't backup my IBM WebSphere environment. However, I copied the whole IBM MQ Installation directory into another folder. Is it possible to restore all IBM MQ environment from the folder I kept without backup?

My MQ version is 8.0.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

If you also backed up your registry and restore the MQ entries, the binaries, and the data, and make sure the files go to the exact same location, then you are good.

If not, there is still hope. First, make sure you have the install media uncompressed in a directory somewhere and your backups safely compressed to a zip file or copied off the Windows host.

Next, follow the instructions in the *[Spring Cleaning a Windows MQ Installation](https://t-rob.net/2015/06/11/spring-cleaning-a-windows-mq-installation/)* article to remove all traces of the old installation from the machine.

Reinstall MQ and/or Explorer from scratch, including up to Fix Pack 4 since that's what you had before.  This will create the registry entries and a clean set of configuration files.

Now go and define queue managers with the same name as the old ones.

Finally, restore the old QMgr data files over top of the new QMgr data files.  If using Explorer, restore its workspace over the new workspace.  Be sure to re-install any plug-ins such as [SupportPac MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupportPacMS0P) as well.

Good luck!

Comment: It is hard to say why not. When the queue managers are created with the old names and configurations it should be possible to drop the old files on top and start them right up.  However, everything has to be in sync.  The new QMgrs must have the same settings for logging, OAM, exits, etc.  Their files must be overlaid while they are not running.  The point-in-time backups from which you are restoring must have been taken with the queue managers stopped, etc.  It's a level of detail that is difficult to reconcile here.

Comment: I copied the whole program files folder before I upgrade my OS. Thus, should it work if I restore all those configuration without any proper backup files from previous MQ configuration?

Comment: Depends. MQ has always allowed (encouraged even) that data and logs be in different directories. On windows this meant you always had the ability to put these anywhere.  In recent versions it even separates binaries into Program Files and data into Program Data.  The only instance in which the answer is "yes" is that all QMgr data and logs were under Program Files and when you restored you restored *only* the QMgr data. Of course, all the other prereqs previously mentioned apply - QMgr stopped when the backup was taken, identical configurations, etc.

Comment: Also on Windows you need to make sure the files restored are owned by the service ID that owns the rest of the QM files.  This doesn't happen by default and you need to sign on as an admin and manually set the file ownership and permissions.